# Quill is it possible to run default module action plus customised one

Tags: javascript, quill

I'd like to insert image in the default way Quill does it (as the blob) but also I'd like to run some extra code when adding image. I know that I can add handler like:

```
quill.getModule('toolbar').addHandler('image', () => {
   // custom code here
});
```

but that's overwriting default action.